# Book that had a ring (or jewelry) that allowed wearer to see the future

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember a scene where a younger person had been given the ring (or jewelry) from an older person who died in a scene prior. The younger person was leading a group of people (possibly dwarves, other friendly creatures in the mix), and they took shelter from the rain under an overhang. The person wearing the ring (or jewelry) foresaw it collapsing on them, so they all moved, and it collapsed.

I'm pretty sure it's a children's book, but not 100%.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it, or anything about the cover? Was this "younger person" a male or female? Even tiny details could help someone find this for you.

Comment: I hate to revisit such an old question, but I don't think it should have been closed as a duplicate of the other question. For one, mine was first (not sure if that matters), and for two, each of us was describing a different scenario with regards to what we recalled of the text.

Seems to me if you ask "a book with Galdalf" and "a book with a Balrog that kills a wizard", while the answer is the same, the questions are not duplicates of each other. Related, yes, not duplicate. This also had an accepted answer, which reading the help means it shouldn't have been marked as duplicate? Not sure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scene you describe is right out of Lloyd Alexander's [Chronicles of Prydain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Prydain).
The main character, assistant pig keeper Taran at some point acquires a magic amulet with 3 lines on it.
Each line represents some power; wisdom, luck, love? etc. (I can't remember exactly)
I can't remember which of the 5 books this happened in though as I read these as a child.
However, I think that the amulet was in either book 3 Castle Lyr or book 4 Taran Wanderer, but don't quote me.
I am 99% sure this series has that scene you describe.

**UPDATE**
It was actually book 2 *The Black Cauldron* where Taran gets the magic item.
Thanks go to John Rennie for the assist. (see below)

Comment: Well remembered, it must be forty years since I read the Prydain books :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie: Yes, it's been about that long for me too... And I added your some of your info to my answer. Thanks

Comment: djm and @JohnRennie thanks for all the answers all those years ago, I think you nailed it, and I'll revisit the series at some point, maybe encouraging my kids to read it.

Answer (score 5):

This is really a comment to djm's answer but it got a bit long for a comment. Anyhow you should accept djm's answer.

The amulet you describe is indeed from the Chronicles of Prydain, though it's in book 2, The Black Cauldron, rather than Castle Llyr or Taran Wanderer. The scene where the overhang collapses is:

> Taran, who had been thoughtfully fingering the clasp, stopped and looked about him uneasily. “Hurry,” he said, “we must leave here at once.”
>   “Taran of Caer Dallben,” Eilonwy cried, “you’re going too far! I can understand coming out of the rain, but I don’t see deliberately going into it.”
>   Nevertheless, she followed; and the companions, at Taran’s urgent command, untethered the horses and ran from the hillside. They had not gone ten paces before the entire slope, weakened by the downpour, collapsed with a loud roar.

The amulet was given to Taran by Adaon, though it's described as a *clasp* rather than an amulet.

> Adaon shook his head. He put his hand to his throat and undid the iron clasp at the collar of his jacket. “Take this,” he said. “Guard it well. It is a small thing, but more valuable than you know.”

Comment: Why not editing djm answer and adding the quotes ? I would be fine with that.... Unless djm says no. Ah, I'm just rambling....