# Which story featured an orphan raised by a wizard who gets a sword from a skeleton on a throne?

Tags: story-identification

From high school I remember a story about a child orphaned and found by a wizard who takes and raises him. The wizard slept with the child till he became older.

The child later on goes out finds a sword in the hands of a skeleton sitting on a throne. He is unable to wield the weapon and is taken by a prince. In the end he fights an evil lord and he takes the blade back, killing the evil lord. The blade is on fire.

Forgive me but my memory is off in some ways.

Comment: Are you asking for a title? Was it a book, movie, cartoon?

Comment: These are all pretty generic fantasy tropes - to me it sounds a bit like [The Sword of Shannara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_of_Shannara), but it could just as easily be something else...

Comment: That could almost fit Conan the Barbarian, couldn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142225/ya-coming-of-age-fantasy-series-protagonist-keeps-pigs (which is newer but is confirmed by OP comment)

Comment: @Otis - Yeah, but it seems as the OP has not confirmed this one, so it can’t be closed (yet).

Comment: @Adamant, oops -- I was looking quickly, and I mistook John Rennie's comment on the answer to be from the OP. Sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 12):

*The Chronicles of Prydain* fits all of those criteria, specifically the first book *The Book of Three*.

The boy is Taran, raised by the wizard Dallben, who finds the sword Dyrnwyn, held by a skeleton in the catacombs beneath Spiral Castle, etc, etc.

Comment: Yes, that has to be it. I should have spotted it - we've just had a story ID question about the Prydain books in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41448/book-that-had-a-ring-or-jewelry-that-allowed-wearer-to-see-the-future :-)